# Arduino 1.6.3 no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, arduino

Trying to create some inline helper classes for then drawing to display.
Wrote some code this summer and then it compiled, now when running latest arduino it doesn't.

Error:

```
tmp.ino: In constructor 'Image::Image(Rectangle, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)':
tmp.ino:24:187: error: no matching function for call to 'Rectangle::Rectangle()'
tmp.ino:24:187: note: candidates are:
tmp.ino:11:5: note: Rectangle::Rectangle(int, int, int, int)
tmp.ino:11:5: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
tmp.ino:3:7: note: Rectangle::Rectangle(const Rectangle&)
tmp.ino:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Error compiling.
```

Here's an example:

```
class Rectangle {
  private:
  public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;

    Rectangle(int ix, int iy, int iwidth, int iheight) {
      x = ix;
      y = iy;
      width = iwidth;
      height = iheight;
    }
};

class Image {
  private:
  public:
    Rectangle bounds;
    String images[10];
    Image(Rectangle s_bounds, String s1, String s2 = "", String s3 = "", String s4 = "", String s5 = "", String s6 = "", String s7 = "", String s8 = "", String s9 = "", String s10 = "") {
      bounds = s_bounds;

      images[0] = s1;
      images[1] = s2;
      images[2] = s3;
      images[3] = s4;
      images[4] = s5;
      images[5] = s6;
      images[6] = s7;
      images[7] = s8;
      images[8] = s9;
      images[9] = s10;

    }
    void UpdatePosition( int s_x, int s_y ) {
      bounds.x = s_x;
      bounds.y = s_y;
    }
};


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Rectangle rect = Rectangle(0,0,200,29);
  rect.x = 20;

  Image img = Image(Rectangle(0,0,10,10), "img.RAW");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

...

Is there some changes for this in latest arduino. When trying to create a simple rectangle.

Error:

```
tmp.ino:20:1: error: 'rect' does not name a type
Error compiling.
```

Code:

```
class Rectangle {
  private:
  public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;

    Rectangle(int ix, int iy, int iwidth, int iheight) {
      x = ix;
      y = iy;
      width = iwidth;
      height = iheight;
    }
};

Rectangle rect = Rectangle(0,0,200,29);
rect.x = 20;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Rectangle` as part of your `Image` class, and aren't constructing it in your initialization list, so it defaults to getting default constructed, and you don't have a default constructor.

You need to initialize your Rectangle with the one passed in inside the initialization list:

```
Image(Rectangle s_bounds, String s1, String s2 = "", String s3 = "", String s4 = "", String s5 = "", String s6 = "", String s7 = "", String s8 = "", String s9 = "", String s10 = "")
 : bounds(s_bounds)
{
  images[0] = s1;
  images[1] = s2;
  images[2] = s3;
  images[3] = s4;
  images[4] = s5;
  images[5] = s6;
  images[6] = s7;
  images[7] = s8;
  images[8] = s9;
  images[9] = s10;

}
```

Your second problem seems to be because you are trying to write code in the global namespace, outside of a function, which isn't valid.  It compiled fine when I moved it to `main()`.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Will try to create classes outside arduino as libraries just to get some training. This really helped.